# Google InApp restore transaction response for subscriptions

Tags: in-app-purchase

I have implemented Google In-App Billing. I have added one month Subscription product.
Let's say I bought this product for July 2012 after this at the end of month I have cancelled this subscription.
Again in September bought this one month subscription. I have created this use case to clear my use case.

Here I want to know that when you will do the restore transaction in month of September, how the entire response comes to you in json format.
Considering that you had subscribed in month of July 2012 then you have cancelled in August 2012 and again later you have subscribed in September 2012.

Few part of the response if I discuss it provides me two major things in json response, one is purchaseTime and other is purchaseToken.

So now the point is when you do the restore transaction in the month of September 2012, and as its a monthly subscription how do you manage the validation of subscriptions not only for month of September 2012 but also for month of July 2012.

Can somebody please give explanation and the way thing works in this scenario. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563733/what-is-the-response-for-restore-transactions-in-case-of-subscription-bought-twi). Still no response, but I'm afraid that in response json you will get only one item with your subscription ID and updated purchase time, order ID and, maybe, updated purchase token. Means that July 2012 subscription data will be overwritten and lost. I can't confirm it right now, because I need to wait for almost three weeks until I can buy same subscription again.

So, you will need a way to store previous subscriptions somewhere (on your server?) and identify them with user (get user's google play email?).

Comment: Hi Sver thanks for information would like to ask that, what do you mean by storing on some server, If I am not wrong then its like you have to store purchaseTime, purchaseToken, productID, against the emailID which has been used to buy that product. One more thing do you think, Is there any way to test this out except than waiting for entire month to test this scenario. Thanks.

Comment: @Devavrata Yes. You need to store purchaseToken, productID and user email. purchaseTime is optional, because you can query [google API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/v1/purchases/get) for it, when checking for subscription validity. And, no, unfortunately, I still haven't found a way to test it without waiting :(

Comment: Thanks Sver :), please let me know if something new you get to know on this.